# Authenticate API retrieve posted data and send to endpoint Pardot

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, api, authentication

Ok I am trying to send data from the front-end (Angular) then send data to the backed (node).

I also need to authenticate my the third party API in the backed by getting my API key by sending a post with my `email`, `password` and `user_key`, once posted I should get a temp `api_key`.

I then use this key and my retried data (from front-end) to post the the API end point.

Im getting a bit lost and am new to angular and node.

I need some help with a few things

- retrieving my posted data from front-end
- Authentication (get `api_key`)
- post full data (`Fname`, `Lname`, `email`, `user_key`, `api_key`)

I have used a npm package found for the API im sending to found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pardot)

Here is where I have got to, any help will be good.

**Backed server/index.js**

```
 // First Get Posted variables

// Code HERE


// Now authenticate the api and get api_key
var pardot = require('pardot');
pardot({
    email: 'tom@mail.co.uk',
    password: 'Password',
    userKey: '345636345345'
})
    .then(function (client) {
        // We've successfully authenticated.
        // Perform some action

        client.prospects.create(email, params, {
            email: 'test',
            Fname: 'tom',
            Lname: 'boom'
        });

    }).fail(function (err) {
    // Failed to authenticate

    alert('failed')
});
```

**Front end post**`

```
FirstModule.controller('formController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.processForm = function (Fname, Lname, email) {
        var data = {
            Fname: $scope.formData.Fname,
            Lname: $scope.formData.Lname,
            email: $scope.formData.email,
        };

//Call the services
        $http.post('server/index', JSON.stringify(data)).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data)
                $scope.formData = "Post Data Submitted Successfully!";

        }, function (response) {
            $scope.formData = "Post Data Submitted Failed";
            $scope.statusval = response.status;
            $scope.statustext = response.statusText;
            $scope.headers = response.headers();
        });
    };
});`
```

**HTML requested**

```
<form name="myForm" id="signup-form" class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2"
                  ng-submit="processForm()"
                  ng-click="postdata(formData)">


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="first-name">First Name*</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-12" name="Fname" placeholder="Enter first name"
           ng-model="formData.Fname"
           ng-required="true">
    <span ng-if="!myForm.Fname.$invalid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok " style="color: green" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="first-name">Last Name*</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-12" name="Lname" placeholder="Enter last name"
           ng-model="formData.Lname"
           ng-required="true">
    <span ng-if="!myForm.Lname.$invalid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok " style="color: green" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="first-name">Email*</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control col-sm-12" name="email" placeholder="Enter valid E-mail"
               ng-model="formData.email"
               ng-required="true">
        <span ng-if="!myForm.email.$invalid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok " style="color: green" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: `retrieving my posted data from front-end` I don't see you usin a `get` method to fetch the data from the back end tho... it'd be nice to post your html as well, so we can see how you use the angular directives.

Comment: No worries @ZombieChowder ill update now to include my HTML